# Gaussian Blur For Entire Image

Tags: filters, convolution, filtering

I am trying to simulate the blurring process (defocus) of a sinusoidal. For this I have build my own Gaussian filter and performed the convolution in Fourier domain.

The result of the blurred signal is shown below.

[image]

The effect in the left and right most part of the blurred image is I assume due to the filter size. If I take sufficiently narrow sized filter the effect becomes less visible.

However, is there a way to get rid of this effect? For example if I take a real picture of a sinusoidal which is out of focus, then one wouldn't observe this effect in the real captured image. What is the correct way to get rid of this effect?

Comment: "if I take a real picture of a sinusoidal which is out of focus" that's because the blur is applied before the photons land on the imager.  If you had a field stop (I think that's the right term) that was applied before the light went into the lens, or if your sine wave were on a rectangular surface that was exactly matched with the camera's field of view, then you would have that effect.

Comment: Telling us _why_ you want to get rid of that effect would be nice -- for example, if you're trying to simulate an out-of-focus camera, it would be helpful to say so.  Please _edit your question_ with any changes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably because of the start-up transients.  You can possibly fix this using the `zi` parameter on the [`filter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function:

[image: screenshot from matlab]

The other option might be to use the [`filtfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) method which attempts to choose the initial conditions:

[image: filtfilt line]

If I take that approach, then the resulting filterings are shown below. The original sinusoid is in blue, the `filter` version (without matching the initial conditions) is in red and the `filtfilt` version is in black +s.

[image: Filtering example]

---

## Matlab code

```
N = 1000;
ts = 0.001;
t = (0:N-1)*ts;
omega = 2*pi*23;
phi = 2*pi*0.829879;
Nsmooth = 10;
Nextra = 10*Nsmooth;

x = sin(omega*t+phi);
xx = [ fliplr(x(1:Nextra)) x fliplr(x((end-Nextra):end)) ];
y = filter(ones(1,Nsmooth)/Nsmooth, 1, x);
zz = filtfilt(ones(1,Nsmooth)/Nsmooth, 1,x);

clf;
plot(x);
hold on;
plot(y,'r');
plot(zz,'k+');
```